# Why is my binary search returning "true" when element isn't found?

Tags: c, cs50

find.c

```
/**
 * find.c
 *
 * Computer Science 50
 * Problem Set 3
 *
 * Prompts user for as many as MAX values until EOF is reached, 
 * then proceeds to search that "haystack" of values for given needle.
 *
 * Usage: ./find needle
 *
 * where needle is the value to find in a haystack of values
 */

#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


#include "helpers.h"

// maximum amount of hay
const int MAX = 65536;

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    // ensure proper usage
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./find needle\n");
        return -1;
    }

    // remember needle
    int needle = atoi(argv[1]);

    // fill haystack
    int size;
    int haystack[MAX];
    for (size = 0; size < MAX; size++)
    {
        // wait for hay until EOF
        printf("\nhaystack[%i] = ", size);
        int straw = GetInt();
        if (straw == INT_MAX)
        {
            break;
        }

        // add hay to stack
        haystack[size] = straw;
    }
    printf("\n");

    // sort the haystack
    sort(haystack, size);

    // try to find needle in haystack
    if (search(needle, haystack, size))
    {
        printf("\nFound needle in haystack!\n\n");
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\nDidn't find needle in haystack.\n\n");
        return 1;
    }
}
```

helpers.c

```
 /**
 * helpers.c
 *
 * Computer Science 50
 * Problem Set 3
 *
 * Helper functions for Problem Set 3.
 */

#include <cs50.h>

#include "helpers.h"

/**
 * Returns true if value is in array of n values, else false.
 */
bool search(int value, int values[], int n)
{
    int temp = values[n/2];
    do {
            if (temp == value)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else if (temp < value)
            {
               temp = temp + temp / 2;
            }
            else if (temp > value)
            {
              temp = temp - temp / 2;
            }
        } while(temp > 1);
    return false;   
}



/**    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
*    {
*       if (values[i] == value)
*        {
*            return true;
*        }
*    }
*    return false;
*}
*/
/**
 * Sorts array of n values.
 */
void sort(int values[], int n)
{
    int swaps = -1;
    do {
        swaps = 0;
        for(int i = 0, temp; i < n; i++)
        {
            if(values[i] > values[i+1])
            {
                temp = values[i+1];
                values[i+1] = values[i];
                values[i] = temp;
                swaps = swaps + 1;
            }
        }
    }while(swaps != 0);
    return;
}
```

I am stumped. The search function is the one in the helpers.c file. When I check the program, it 'returns 0' even when the number can't be found in the array. I would love some insight into why it's doing this.

Comment: I could be misunderstanding your code, but it looks like your search function may be incorrect. The problem that I see is in the `else if` and `else` statements. I believe that you should be setting `n=n+n/2` or `n=n-n/2` not `temp=temp+temp/2` and `temp=temp-temp/2`. It appears that your temp value is the value in the array you are examining, not the index in the array (i.e., you are not actually checking each element of the array).

Comment: `search()` has troubles.  `temp = temp + temp / 2;` and `temp = temp - temp / 2;` are certainly amiss.  Try stepping though this line by line.

Comment: For a binary search, I suggest 3 variables: `bot` and `top` and `mid`. In each iteration `mid = (top + bot) / 2;` then you replace `bot` or `top` with `mid` depending on the comparison. I prefer to keep `top` index out of array range, so the match will never be `top`.

Answer (score 1):

You should compare each time values[temp] with value and not temp with values .Also  you shouldn't give the value values[n/2] but n/2 instead,and your implementation does not covers if the value is the values[0] because you have the condition  `while(temp >1)` so temp will always be >1 ,neither if value is values[2] (example values[]={1,2,3,4,5} ,value =5).
So you should add in the end:

```
if (values[1]==value || values[0]==value ) return true;
```

Finally if value is greater than the max element of values temp will be constantly incrementing so you will have infinite loop so I changed the condition to :

```
while(temp >1 && temp<n);
```

As recommended in the comments you could better write the search function by keeping low ,middle and upper bound variables  instead of usesing only temp .

```
   bool search(int value, int values[], int n)
{
    int temp = n/2;
    do {
            if (values[temp] == value)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else if (values[temp] < value)
            {
               temp = temp + temp/ 2;
            }
            else if (values[temp] > value)
            {
              temp = temp /2; //temp-temp/2 equals to temp/2
            }
        } while(temp >1 && temp<n);
    if (values[1]==value || values[0]==value ) return true;
    return false;   
}
```